# wordpress — Get posts if they had a thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

Who knows, how can i get only posts, what had a thumbnail picture?
I didn't find anything in WP documentation. Please, help!
Filters of get_posts() are not including thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php 
   $loop = new WP_Query( array('meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'post_type' => 'post')); 
   while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

That will return all `posts` that has a thumbnail (featured image) attached.

Comment: Yes! This is a best decision! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can check the post have thumb or not using `has_post_thumbnail( $post_id );`

**example :**

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if(has_post_thumbnail( the_ID )) {
 #code....
}
endwhile;
?>
```

**[Function Reference/has post thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail)**